# stop one of the parent click events from firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

HI,

I am using a greybox on the following element:

```
<a href="<? echo $rctiGrayBox; ?>" class="greybox" widt="800" heigh="800" id="rctiGrayBox" title="RCTI">View RCTI</a>
```

This 'a' element is contained in TR which fires an event when ever we click 'View RCTI'.
I can stop that click event from firing by using `stopPropagation()` but using this function also stops the greybox to work and instead of showing the data in greybox it shows the data on a new page.

Theoretically when i use `stopPropagation()` on my 'a' tag it stops the all the events from firing. I need a way with which i can only stop the click event on  but should not stop any event related to Greybox.

Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for  `event.preventDefault()`.

That will prevent the default behavior (guess what..), in this case will stop the anchor from linking.

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/KDU48/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;"></a>
```

this will stop the bubble up event in the browser. But bound eventhandlers will still work

Comment: yes you are right 'return false' will stop bubbling. Stopping the bubbling means stopping all the parent click events.